# Hook in webpack compilation

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am using webpack 2.4.2 for an AngularJS 1.6(Typescript) based application.
When I modify my .ts, .js, .less etc files webpack automatically checks for lint errors and reports them.

I am not sure how webpack automatically detects changes and run lint, however, I want to run custom commands like checking for tslint errors. Any pointers as to how it could be achieved?

Comment: Presumably it is in your Webpack config file under `loaders` or `rules`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest webpack, here is how you configure eslint. You however will need to find a tslint loader.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: 'eslint-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I get the following error
`ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'eslint-loader' in '/home/cbdev1/cb/bas/client'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.ts
`
As per last comment on https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1083
`resolve: {
   modules: [
     path.join(__dirname, "src"),
     "node_modules"
   ]
  }`

However, I already have it in my config

Comment: i assume eslint-loader is in your package.json?